# Multiple workers each with multiple cores

Tags: matlab

I have an external MEX process that I am calling from MATLAB. This code is written in parallel and can use 6 cores (12 threads) efficiently.

My machine has 12 cores (24 threads). Is there anyway to create 2 parallel workers (each using 6 cores/12 threads) and then each of them call that MEX program simultaneously. The MEX program is thread safe.

Thanks!

Comment: MEX function files don't run as external programs. They are DLLs that are loaded into the Matlab process's memory space, and run there internally. Does that matter?

Comment: When you say "parallel" - do you want each MEX "program" to run in its own process? Or is it okay if each is running on its own set of worker threads all within the same process?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `NumThreads` property of your `parallel.Cluster` - either on the cluster instance directly, or by modifying your cluster profile using the [Cluster Profile Manager](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/discover-clusters-and-use-cluster-profiles.html). Here's the programmatic way:

```
c = parcluster('local');
c.NumThreads = 3;
parpool(c, 2);
spmd, maxNumCompThreads, end % each worker gets the answer 3
```

Your MEX code should ideally use the result of `maxNumCompThreads` to determine how many threads it should use.

Comment: This assumes OP is using the Parallel Computing Toolbox, right? I don't know if that's the case.

Comment: @AndrewJanke yes, you're quite right it does. I inferred that from the phrase "parallel workers" - that's the terminology used by PCT - but it might not be what the OP intended at all...

Comment: Cool. That would have been my guess too just based on the term "parallel", but they also mention that their MEX code is "thread safe", and MEX is an in-process mechanism in the first place. So maybe they actually want multi-threading instead of multi-processing? Or just a mechanism without using the PCT? Just guessing here.